# Reading the RSP register from Microsoft C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, 64-bit

Since inline assembler is not available in Microsoft C++ when compiling for the x64 architecture, I can't figure out how to access the RSP register (stack pointer). I know I can read it using RtlCaptureContext, but this would also perform a lot of unwanted operations. Also it would be a few thousand times slower (for my purposes, not acceptable). If I write a separate ASM function, the RSP would obviously change, so that is not an alternative either.

So how does one read the contents for the x64 RSP register using Microsoft C++?

Comment: Maybe there is another way to do whatever you want to do than reading RSP. What is your actual purpose ?

Comment: @Joachim: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Disregard my (now deleted) answer. The win64 stack has to be aligned on a 16 bytes boundary, so a separate function can't correctly tell `rsp`.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to read the register as it is clearly non-portable.  I think you misunderstood why inline assembler was pulled.

Comment: Also note that in optimized code, RSP could change in the middle of a function's code should the compiler decide that it is a good idea.

Comment: @Steve-o: It's his computer, for heaven's sake. Why shouldn't he read RSP if that's what he wants to do?

Comment: @TonkY Microsoft's stance on x64 assembler is made, they've determined code quality improves without it.

Comment: @Steve-o The RSP does not change in the middle of a function. This would make crash exception unwinding.

Comment: Almost two years later, we have a post in the [Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/01/10415241.aspx?Redirected=true) that anyone should read when looking for a solution for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it indirectly using the `_AddressOfReturnAddress()` (see [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7k.aspx)) intrinsic.
Obviously, you do not get to know for sure where the current stack frame stops, but you can guesstimate it with whatever stack variables you have and by looking at the generated assembly.

In combination with Olipro's suggestion: using `_AddressOfReturnAddress()` in a standalone function, getting the stack address becomes seriously easy. Not to mention that there is a great probability for a function written in C containing only a call to this intrinsic to be inlined.

Comment: No good. I need the RSP as a runtime value to traverse the call stack using cached frame sizes.

Comment: @Joachim: Actually, I believe that my answer is equivalent to Olipro's one, without assembly code.

Comment: Actually, I think you are right. I should be able to use the _AddressOfReturnAddress(). Let me try it and I'll revisit this question.

Comment: The intrinsic good inlined and it works great. Changed the accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so, I've had a fiddle with it and got it working; you can't get the compiler to inline it, but you fortunately don't need it to, just drop this into a .s or .asm file and compile with `ml64 /c yourasm.s" and hand the .obj to the linker.

```
.CODE

     getRSP PROC
     mov rax, rsp
     add rax, 8
     ret
     getRSP ENDP
     END
```

then on the C side of things all you need is `extern "C" __int64 getRSP();`

Comment: the call causes the stack pointer to be decremented by 8 bytes; if you increment by 8 bytes, you have its original value.

Comment: Of course. Discarding the return address from a called function will reveal the callers SP. Thanks!!

Comment: @Olipro
I found that using _AddressOfReturnAddress was somewhat cleaner without the assembly language and as I could avoid a call. Upvote for a good solution though...

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the `_AddressOfReturnAddress` intrinsic? It's not the `RSP` register itself, but that's somewhat volatile in its own right.

Comment: No good. I need the RSP as I'm traversing the call stack based on cached frame sizes.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways I can think of doing this:

1) create an ASM file with the instruction to move rsp into rax and return and then see if you can get the compiler to inline it.

2) if the above is a no-go, declare a volatile pointer variable and use the `__nop()` intrinsic to give yourself enough space to patch the necessary instruction in post build (or heck, just assign a value to your volatile pointer a few times and replace that)

Answer (score 0):

[`__getCFS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dz4bac2.aspx), [`__getPSP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdtwdsf.aspx), possibly [`__getReg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcb3wece.aspx)?

You could also link with a MinGW-w64 object file that does the assembler inline.

Comment: @Necrolis IPF is IA64?  Go figure.

Comment: The joys of intel naming: x86-64 always gets shortened to x64, then people assume x64 must be the same as IA64, cause IA32 is x86, but IA64 is a totally different architecture, this is why msdn uses IPF to denote IA64 (really disappointing to find a nice intrinsic, only to see its for IPF only).